# Apache 2.4 and Reverse proxy - not redirecting when using VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd.conf

I'm running Apache 2.4 on AWS Linux as httpd. I've a single domain, and all requests are directed via `/conf/httpd.conf` using `Listen: 80` and `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"`. My current domain does use SSL, with the certificates installed on the server.

I'm now at a point where I'd like to introduce a reverse proxy setup to point at another server if a directory match exists. So, for example:

- `http://example.com/` should show files from `/var/www/html`
- `http://example.com/myAPI/` should be redirected to `http://12.34.56.78:9876/`

I've been attempting to follow the documentation [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/reverse_proxy.html), and some examples [here](https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/116-simple-apache-reverse-proxy-example#:%7E:text=Apache%20can%20be%20used%20as,access%20to%20the%20outside%20world.), and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-with-mod_proxy-on-centos-7), but seem to wind up in various states of not being able to start the http daemon, or the daemon successfully starting but not performing any redirects because the /myAPI/ call is not being redirected.

I've been attempting various versions of this in `/conf/httpd.conf` followed by a service restart.

```
#About line 44 in an otherwise largely unmodified config file
#Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>

   ProxyPreserveHost on
   SSLProxyEngine on

   ServerName example.com

   ProxyPass        "/myAPI" "http://12.34.56.78:9876/"
   ProxyPassReverse "/myAPI" "http://12.34.56.78:9876/"

</VirtualHost>
```

Note: I am not running a default-site.conf file. I, quite frankly, am not sure if it will make a difference, and when I've tried to set it up I seem to cause a litany of other issues. So if my example is achievable from the default httpd.conf I'd prefer to work in there.

Comment: Your config looks fine. Does the Apache error log tell you anything useful? Try turning up the log level, say to `LogLevel trace3`.